# Intuition - difference between Moore spectrum and Eilenberg-Mac Lane spectrum

Tags: homotopy-theory, stable-homotopy, stable-homotopy-category, bousfield-localization

I know very little about algebraic topology, and more about $k$-linear stable $\infty$-categories (i.e. homological algebra).

Given an abelian group $A$, there is the Eilenberg-Mac Lane spectrum $HA$, for which: $\pi_{< 0}(\cdot) = 0$, $\pi_0 (\cdot) = A$, $\pi_{>0}(\cdot) = 0$. There is also the Moore spectrum $SA$, for which $\pi_{<0}(\cdot) = 0$, $\pi_{=0} (\cdot)= A$, $H_{> 0} (\cdot , \mathbb{Z}) = 0$.

I more-or-less have some feeling for $HA$ (under Dold-Kan, it is simply $A$, so one simply gets connected deloopings $BA$, $BBA$, etc. making the infinite loop space structure explicit).

I have no feeling what-so-ever about $SA$.

But reading about Bousfield localization, it seems that most the standard examples are with $SA$. How to understand this for a novice? Say, for $p$-localization and $p$-completion, how do I understand that I "want" to use the Moore spectrum and not the Eilenberg-Mac Lane spectrum?

Or, at least, what is the rationale for introducing Moore spectra?

Thank you

Comment: Denis's answer is 100% the reason why the specific object S/p appears in the theory of localization. You could still ask whether you _could_ use HZ/p, and here the answer is somewhat unintuitive: for connective spectra, localization at S/p and at HZ/p agree, and so you cannot tell the difference before passing to nonconnective spectra, which are somewhat exotic objects. The spectrum $KU := \Sigma^\infty_+ \mathbb CP^\infty[\beta^{-1}]$ is a concrete example of a spectrum with $H_*(KU; Z)$ rational, hence $H_*(KU; Z/p)$ and $L_{HZ/p} KU$ null, but $L_{S/p} KU$ nontrivial.

Comment: @EricPeterson: Thank you! I will have to think about it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm not sure I can answer to the general question, but I can explain why the Moore spectrum $\mathbb{S}/p$ shows up in the discussion of Bousfield localizations.

This is just the cofiber of multiplication by $p$ from $\mathbb{S}$ to itself. Hence saying that for a spectrum $X$ we have $X\wedge \mathbb{S}/p=0$ means simply that multiplication by $p$ acts on $X$ as an equivalence. So $X$ is $\mathbb{S}[1/p]$-local iff it is $\mathbb{S}/p$-acyclic. From standard localization arguments (plus the fact that $\mathbb{S}/p$ is a finite spectrum) you get the fracture square relating $\mathbb{S}[1/p]$-localization and $p$-completion (i.e. the "complementary localization" of $\mathbb{S}[1/p]$-localization).

So, essentially, the reason it shows up is because the Moore spectrum is the layer of the diagram
$$ \mathbb{S} \xrightarrow{p} \mathbb{S}\xrightarrow{p}\mathbb{S}\xrightarrow{p}\mathbb{S}\xrightarrow{p}\cdots $$
that computes $\mathbb{S}[1/p]$-localization. From this it is clear that $\mathbb{S}/p^n$ is also going to be relevant to the study of $p$-completion (since these are just the "higher" layers of the tower), and from there to
$$\mathbb{S}/p^\infty = \mathbb{S}\mathbb{Q}_p/\mathbb{Z}_p = \mathrm{colim}\,\mathbb{S}/p^n$$
and
$$\mathbb{S}\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}=\bigvee_p \mathbb{S}/p^\infty$$
is just a small step.

Comment: Thank you! This now makes perfect sense. But for p=2, it seems that the cofiber of multiplication by 2 on the sphere spectrum has $\pi_0$ with four elements, so this should differ from the Moore spectrum as defined in my question, no?

Comment: @Sasha No, $π_0\mathbb{S}/2=H_0\mathbb{S}/2=\mathbb{Z}/2$. Maybe you're confounding it with $[\mathbb{S}/2,\mathbb{S}/2]=\mathbb{Z}/4$? (Yes, it is a bit counterintuitive but this nontrivial extension is secretly coming from $\pi_1\mathbb{S}$)

Comment: Oops, I am used to cohomological convention, so I simply calculated wrongly the long exact sequence of homotopy groups for the cofiber sequence. Thank you!

Comment: @Sasha Well, as I'm fond of saying, the cohomological convention is the tool of the Devil. Don't fall for it! ;)

Comment: I don't quite have a say, since this is so common in homological algebra (representaiton theory etc.) that I can't go against it. But perhaps it makes sense to put $\pi_1$ in negative degree, since it represents "smaller" stuff? (like the cardinality of $BG$ is $|G|^{-1}$ etc.) Anyway, probably one can find justification for each.

Comment: @Sasha In case it wasn't clear I was joking. But when doing homotopy theory using cohomological convention means that the homotopy group of a space are all in nonpositive degree, and that is rather annoying :)

Comment: Is it correct that every spectrum is an $H\bbZ$-module (where morally $n \in \pi_0 (H\bbZ)$ acts by multiplication by $n$) and the Moore spectrum construction is the left adjoint of this $Spectra \to D(\bbZ)$ functor (where $D(\bbZ)$ is the derived category of $\bbZ$-modules, which is the same, I believe, as spectrum modules over $H\bbZ$)?

Comment: @Sasha No. Spectra in general are not $H\mathbb{Z}$-modules, they are only $\mathbb{S}$-modules. In fact the (∞-)category of $H\mathbb{Z}$-modules is equivalent to $D(\mathbb{Z})$. Moreover the Moore spectrum construction [is not even functorial](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/163472/section-of-the-homology-functor-on-spectra)! If you want to continue discussing, please come to the [homotopy theory chatroom](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9417/homotopy-theory) so the system doesn't yell at us :)